# Passing 0 to function with default value

Tags: php, function, default-value

Im currently testing a simple PHP function.

I want to to return the currently value of a field if the function is called without any parameter passed or set a new value if a parameter is passed.
Strange thing is: if I pass 0 (var_dump is showing correct value int(1) 0), the function goes into the if branch like i called the function without any value and i just don't get why.

function:

```
public function u_strasse($u_strasse = 'asdjfklhqwef'){
  if($u_strasse == 'asdjfklhqwef'){
    return $this->u_strasse;
  } else {
    // set new value here
  }
}
```

either `u_strasse()` or `u_strasse(0)` gets me in the if branch.

Comment: In the meanwhile I came up with an even better solution, I´m using the default value only PHP reports a warning when calling the function without a parameter and use func_num_args() to choose what to do. if func_num_args() === 0 -> return value, else set new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing variables of different types (specifically strings and numbers), both values will be converted to a number. Therefore, your 'asdjfklhqwef' converts to 0 (number), the comparison is true.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks. Already had a look at this link but i kinda misslooked this. That was the answer i was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use null as the default value:

```
public function u_strasse($u_strasse = null)
{
    if ($u_strasse === null) { $u_strasse = 'asdjfklhqwef'; }

    // rest of function
}
```

Comment: Good solution, never tried it with null before so thanks for that. Still i don´t get why PHP is interpreting 0 as default value if it isn´t.

Answer (score 1):

Use === instead of ==:

```
public function u_strasse($u_strasse = 'asdjfklhqwef'){
  if($u_strasse === 'asdjfklhqwef'){
    return $this->u_strasse;
  } else {
    // set new value here
  }
}
```

In case of == php tries to convert 'asdjfklhqwef' to number (because you pass $u_strasse as a number) and  (int)'asdjfklhqwef' equals 0. To avoid this behavior you need to  compare strictly (===)

Read more about difference in == and === [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

Pass '0' instead of 0. The former will be a string. 
You can cast it like this:

```
$myvar = 0;

u_strasse((string)$myvar);
```

Comment: I know I´m just curious why 0 is treated as default value. If I test with === it works

Comment: PHP will type-convert for you automatically. since you pass in a 0 and that's on the left, the string will be converted to an int as well, and end up being '0' as well. If your string had (say) a '9' as its first character, you'd end up with `0 == 9` and go through the false path.